# Convert jquery code to angular code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a weather app using ionic angular , my app is almost done , but I want add some add-on. This jQuery code I want to  it to be converted to angular:

```
var tempCelsius = Math.round(data.current_observation.temp_c);
        if (tempCelsius < 15){
            $("#temp").css("color", "#00DFF9");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 20){
            $("#temp").css("color", "#21DBE1");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 25) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#A0FF74");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 30) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "##FEB900");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 35) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "##FE7400");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 40) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#FE5100");
        } else if (tempCelsius > 45) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#FE0000");
        } else if (tempCelsius > 50) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "##FE0000");
        } else if (tempCelsius > 55) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#E8250C");
        }


        $("#temp").html(Math.round(tempCelsius )+ "&#176;C");
```

I try to make it like that for angular but it is not working :

```
    $scope.tempco =function(tempco){    
    var tempCelsius = Math.round(weather.currently.temperature);
        if (tempCelsius < 15){
            $("#temp").css("color", "#00DFF9");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 20){
            $("#temp").css("color", "#21DBE1");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 25) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#A0FF74");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 30) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "##FEB900");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 35) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "##FE7400");
        } else if (tempCelsius < 40) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#FE5100");
        } else if (tempCelsius > 45) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#FE0000");
        } else if (tempCelsius > 50) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "##FE0000");
        } else if (tempCelsius > 55) {
            $("#temp").css("color", "#E8250C");
        }       
    }
```

html :

```
{{tempco(weather.currently.temperature)| number:1}} &deg;
```

Comment: you need to return a value from your `tempco` function. currently you return nothing so `tempco(weather.currently.temperature)` will be **undefined**

Comment: Did you get any  error ?

Comment: what the solution ?

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO no error

Answer (score 1):

you need write a **directive** to handle dom operation

**angularjs**

```
YourApp.directive('tempCelsius', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            tempCelsius:'=', //or @
        }
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var $el = $(element); //need jquery js. (don't recommend use jquery & angularjs)
            var tempCelsius = scope.tempCelsius;
            if (tempCelsius < 15){
                $el.css("color", "#00DFF9");
            } else if (tempCelsius < 20){
                $el.css("color", "#21DBE1");
            } else if (tempCelsius < 25) {
                $el.css("color", "#A0FF74");
            } else if (tempCelsius < 30) {
                $el.css("color", "##FEB900");
            } else if (tempCelsius < 35) {
                $el.css("color", "##FE7400");
            } else if (tempCelsius < 40) {
                $el.css("color", "#FE5100");
            } else if (tempCelsius > 45) {
                $el.css("color", "#FE0000");
            } else if (tempCelsius > 50) {
                $el.css("color", "##FE0000");
            } else if (tempCelsius > 55) {
                $el.css("color", "#E8250C");
            }   
        }
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<span temp-celsius="12"> //use @
<span temp-celsius="info.tempCelsius"> //use =, value in scope
```

Answer (score 0):

For no value being displayed, your function returns nothing. Add a return statement at the end. As for the css styling, angular has an [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive that will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$scope.tempco =function(tempco){    
    var tempCelsius = Math.round(weather.currently.temperature);
        if (tempCelsius < 15){
            return "#00DFF9";
        } else if (tempCelsius < 20){
            return "#21DBE1";
        } else if (tempCelsius < 25) {
            return "#A0FF74";
        } else if (tempCelsius < 30) {
            return "##FEB900";
        } else if (tempCelsius < 35) {
            return "##FE7400";
        } else if (tempCelsius < 40) {
            return "#FE5100";
        } else if (tempCelsius > 45) {
            return "#FE0000";
        } else if (tempCelsius > 50) {
            return "##FE0000";
        } else if (tempCelsius > 55) {
            return "#E8250C";
        }       
    }
```

and html:

```
  <div style="background-color:{{tempco(weather.currently.temperature)}}">
  {{weather.currently.temperature}}
  </div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/112g/h6p4xkyu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $scope.tempco =function(tempco){ 
 $scope.colorCode = "";   
var tempCelsius = Math.round(weather.currently.temperature);
    if (tempCelsius < 15){
        $scope.colorCode = "#00DFF9";
    } else if (tempCelsius < 20){
        $scope.colorCode = "#21DBE1";
    } else if (tempCelsius < 25) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#A0FF74";
    } else if (tempCelsius < 30) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#FEB900";
    } else if (tempCelsius < 35) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#FE7400";
    } else if (tempCelsius < 40) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#FE5100";
    } else if (tempCelsius > 45) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#FE0000";
    } else if (tempCelsius > 50) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#FE0000";
    } else if (tempCelsius > 55) {
        $scope.colorCode = "#E8250C";
    }       
}

$scope.tempco(parameter); //pass any value as parameter while calling
```

html

```
<div ng-style="{'color': colorCode}"> 
   {{tempco(weather.currently.temperature)| number:1}}&deg;
</div>
```